# How do you add Skin Modifier with radius 0.1 without using bpy.ops?

Tags: python, modifiers

How do you add a *Skin Modifier* with radius of $0.1$ without using the context sensitive function `bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_skin_add()`?

```
obj.modifiers.new('MySkinModifier', 'SKIN')

# missing code here to add vertices like bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_skin_add()

for v in obj.data.skin_vertices[0].data:
    v.radius = 0.1, 0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer appears to be you don't.

The long answer is that `bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_skin_add()` in [`meshdata.c` at line 881](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/editors/mesh/mesh_data.c#L881) calls an internal function `BKE_mesh_ensure_skin_customdata()` in [`mesh.c` at line 647](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/mesh.c#L647) and that function is not exposed through the Python API.

The longer answer is that your call to `obj.modifiers.new()` already invokes `bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_skin_add()` So your question is really how to fill in `obj.data.skin_vertices` with new data.  Perhaps you can use the code from `BKE_mesh_ensure_skin_customdata()` as a starting point? It creates a `bmesh`, adds a custom layer to it and then iterates through the `bmesh` filling in the layer.

Comment: thanks for your response! I will look into this